# How can I go to symbol across python files in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Essentially I want to be able to do the following https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_open-symbol-by-name in a python workspace in visual studio code.

It returns `No symbols matching` when attempting to search. Any way to get this working?

Comment: Good question. To me, it just seems like the python support is abyssmal. Sad.

Answer (score 5):

There used to be an issue but it seems to be fixed now, it works for me. For people stumbling upon this question wondering how to look for symbols across files, use the `Open symbol by name` feature.

1. From the command palette `cmd/ctrl + shift + p > Go to Symbole in Workspace...`
2. Starting the command with `#` `cmd/ctrl + shift + p > # my_symbol`
3. Using the default keybinding `ctrl/cmd + T`
4. Overwrite the default keybinding
5. Include symbol search in Quick Open: `"search.quickOpen.includeSymbols": true`

Example using keybinding:

[image: screenshot of keybinding]

https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/editingevolved#_open-symbol-by-name